# Node-json2html could not find its declaration module

Tags: reactjs, npm

Do you guys have any problem with `node-json2html`? I installed it using npm.

But somehow it gives me an error like this:

> could not find a declaration file for module  node-json2html

By the way, I am using ReactJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-json2html` is for node server. That's the reason you can't use it on ReactJS. 
You must use `json2html` library on your ReactJS

http://json2html.com/#getstarted